# How to pass an Object to a method in Symfony2?

Tags: object, symfony, php

When clicking on a link, I pass an object id in My AlbumController I have :

```
<?php

namespace YM\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {

        if ($id > 0) {
            // We get the EntityManager
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getEntityManager();

            // We get the Entity that matches id: $id
            $article = $em->getRepository('YMTestBundle:Album')
                          ->find($id);

            // If the Album doesn't exist, we throw out a 404 error
            if ($article == null) {
              throw $this->createNotFoundException('Album[id='.$id.'] do not exist');
            }


              // We delete the article
            $em->remove($article);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Album deleted successfully');

              // Puis on redirige vers l'accueil
              return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('ymtest_Artist') );
        }
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('ymtest_dashboard') );
    }
}
```

And it works.

But is saw something on stackoverflow, where they pass an object (I heard S2 is able to find it itself) that I'd like to reproduce:

```
<?php

namespace YM\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function deleteAction(Album $album)
    {
        // We get the EntityManager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getEntityManager();

        // If the Album doesn't exist, we throw out a 404 error
        if ($lbum == null) {
          throw $this->createNotFoundException('Album[id='.$id.'] do not exist');
        }


          // We delete the article
        $em->remove($album);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Album deleted successfully');

          // Puis on redirige vers l'accueil
          return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('ymtest_Artist') );

        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('ymtest_dashboard') );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I have :

> Class YM\TestBundle\Controller\Album does not exist

Why ?
Thx

Comment: You need to import `Album`
`use Path\To\Your\Namespace\Album;`
However, this won't make symfony pass you an `Album` object

Comment: I just added "use YM\TestBundle\Controller\AlbumController;"
But I get an error (Cannot declare class YM\TestBundle\Controller\Album\AlbumController because the name is already in use in E:\Programmes\wamp\www\Symfony\src\YM\TestBundle\Controller\AlbumController.php on line 10).
I tried with use YM\TestBundle\Entity\Album;, same

Comment: When you say "You need to import Album". Where do you mean I should Import it ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you forgot about use statement:

```
use  YM\TestBundle\Entity\Album;
```

In your case symfony looks for Album class in current namespace (which is Controller).

Moveover you may want read more about ParamConverter (the mechanism which you ask about):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Try add something like that to your method annotation (And don't forgot about appropriate namespace for this annotation):

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

(...)

/**
 * @ParamConverter("album", class="YMTestBundle:Album")
 */
public function deleteAction(Album $album)
{
   (...)
```

:

Comment: That works fine thx. Didn't have to use any annotation though.